# Is it possible encapulate spring form tags inside custom tags? (see update 1)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

In my current spring project, I create the follow custom tag to define a form:

```
public class MainFormTag extends TagSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String action;

    private String classe;

    public void doTag() throws IOException {
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        out.println("<form method='post' action='"+action+"'></form>");
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() {
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

this tag is used this way:

```
<c:url value="/${entity}/cadastra" var="cadastra"/>
<custom:MainForm action="${cadastra}" classe="${command['class'].simpleName}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>
</custom:MainForm>
```

but when I deploy the application and open the page whit this form, nothing is displayed in the page. What I am doing wrong here?

my customTag.tld is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>custom</short-name>
    <uri>/WEB-INF/customTag</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>MainForm</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form.MainFormTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>action</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>classe</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>Input</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.InputTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>Select</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.SelectTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>EmbedSelect</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.EmbedSelectTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>Textarea</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.TextareaTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>Checkbox</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.CheckboxTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>label</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>Radiobutton</name>
        <tag-class>com.spring.loja.config.taglib.form_control.RadiobuttonTag</tag-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>ordem</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>label</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>value</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

**UPDATE 1**

I solve the problem described above replacing the method doTag by the pair doStartTag and doEndTag. But now I have another question: Is it possible use spring form tags inside the custom tag class? In this way, the application must transform the custom tag in spring form tag and this last one in the final form tag which will be delivered to the browser.

the methods, if this approach is possible, get to be like that:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    try {
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        out.println("<form:form method='post' action='"+action+"'>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JspException("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}

public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    try {
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        out.println("</form:form>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JspException("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return EVAL_PAGE;
}
```

Comment: Not much point in printing out `<form...></form>` with no inputs between the opening and closing. View source. Is the  `<form...></form>` (which will be invisible on the page) in the HTML source?

Comment: @developerwjk I have other custom tags for the other inputs inside the form. In this moment, I am just testing this first tag. But no `<form...></form>` is displayed in the HTML source.